# Check when a privilege was granted - PostgreSQL

Tags: permissions, audit, postgresql-10

Is there any information_schema view that can tell when an object privilege was granted?

The pg_namespace view doesn't have that.

```
select  
  *
from pg_namespace
join lateral (
  SELECT
    *
  from
    aclexplode(nspacl) as x
) a on true
join pg_user e on a.grantee = e.usesysid
join pg_user r on a.grantor = r.usesysid 
 where e.usename = '<<MY_USERNAME>>';
```

Comment: No, Postgres does not store this information.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. If you could post this as an answer, I'll accept and close this.